# IE ignoring 'value' attribute of submit button, and using the display text instead - get around?

Tags: forms, internet-explorer, button, input, submit

I just learned that IE uses a button's display text as the value submitted, which completely breaks my form.

I have two buttons, a previous button, and a next button. Obviously, I want these to say "Previous" and "Next."

PHP generates the value for these buttons, basically the step. So, if we were on step 3, previous would have a value of 2, and next would have a value of 4. These are both in the same form, so I can't just put a hidden input in there with the value I really want.

Is there any way to make a submit button in IE that will have a different value than what the button displays to the user?

```
<button name="submit" value="2">Previous</button>
<button name="submit" value="4">Next</button>
```

These two buttons, when submitted, shows this for the POST data:

```
[submit] => Previous
[submit] => Next
```

instead of...

```
[submit] => 2
[submit] => 4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<button type="Submit" name="Submit" value="REAL_VALUE">SOME TEXT</button>
```

will give a different value than the text. (Updated to be submit button)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be submitting the form, now.

Comment: You didnt say it was a submit button.

Comment: "Is there any way to make a submit button in IE that will have a different value than what the button displays to the user?"

Comment: I appreciate the help, Mike. But the issue is that IE ignores the 'value' attribute and uses 'SOME TEXT'.

Comment: You can submit the form using jQuery, and set your attributes as you see fit.

Comment: Here is a writeup on that: http://rommelsantor.com/clog/2012/03/12/fixing-the-ie7-submit-value/

Comment: Thanks for that. I suppose submitting the form with jQuery wouldn't hurt.